# SAS: Copy one observation onto another?

Tags: sas

I have dataset M

```
number id_no date
1      123   3/3/2012
2      123   3/3/2012
3      .     .
4      .     .
```

How do I copy 123 and 3/3/2012 into the obs 4 & 5.

Comment: what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: You can use retain statement to do this

Comment: Look at at this answer from @Joe 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16421386/fill-the-blank-values-of-a-variable-with-the-previous-non-blank-value-sas-9-3)

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there.

```
data one;
input
number id_no date mmddyy10.;
format date mmddyy10.;
datalines;
1      123   3/3/2012
2      123   3/3/2012
3      .     .
4      .     .
5      456   .
;
run;

proc sort data = one;
by number;
run;

data two;
set one;
retain _id_no _date;
if missing(_id_no) then _id_no = id_no;
if missing(id_no) then id_no = _id_no;

if missing(_date) then _date = date;
if missing(date) then date = _date;
drop _id_no _date;
run;
```